# Django reverse returns the error 'view_name' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, routes

Here is my view:

```py
class OrganizationViewSet(AbstractEntityViewSet):

    serializer_class = OrganizationSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    model = serializer_class.Meta.model
    queryset = model.objects.all()
```

I registered it as follows in urls.py:

```py
router.register(r"organizations", OrganizationViewSet, basename="organizations")
```

Now, I am trying to use `build_absolute_url` as follows:

```py
HttpRequest().build_absolute_uri(reverse('organizations', args=(self.parent_organization.slug,))),
```

It returns the following error:

```py
  File "C:\Samir\Pro\near_shop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 86, in reverse  
    return resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Samir\Pro\near_shop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 694, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'organizations' not found. 'organizations' is 
not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

The basename on the router is "organizations", then why it can't find it?

Comment: Can you show your `urls.py` file ? It's seems that you are not defined a view with **organizations** as name.

Comment: I reedited the question, second code block is on urls.py. Moreover, I checked that the view has the basename as None in its attributes.

Comment: Have you added this pattern to the `urlpatterns` variable like this ?  `urlpatterns += router.urls`